# Looking for a GSM Tower LAC/CellID Database for The UK - 2 Byte IDs Required

Tags: api, gps, geolocation, gsm, cellular-network

I'm developing a server system for a GPS asset tracking device and I'm looking to use GSM positioning to act as a back up in the event of a loss of GPS lock.

The devices I'm developing for return a 2 byte cell ID but the cell ID database APIs I've seen so far seem to provide 4-byte IDs.

Can anyone recommend an API that includes 2 byte IDs?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thank you to the guys who offered advice.
I've managed to persuade finance to stump up for an API key for the Google Maps Geolocation API in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Have you already checked the list available in [wikipedia.org](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cell_ID#Public_Cell_ID_databases), would consider one of those using the 2byte version. The page also explain nicely the difference between the 2 & 4 byte codes

Comment: I had looked at those listed and found that they were giving out the 4 byte addresses.  As the tracker's GSM modem was returning only the 2 byte identifier, I'm unable to calculate the UTMS cell ID to request. The explaination of how the 4 byte ID works was certainly of interest to me.  Thanks for that pointer.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider the OpenCellID project. They provide download from the following URL.

http://downloads.opencellid.org/

Comment: Thanks Michael.  They were the first one I tried.  Sadly they only have the 4 byte IDs on record.